# Principal component analysis vs feature removal

Tags: machine-learning, principal-components

I'm quite new to machine learning and just got introduced to principle component analysis as a dimensionality reduction method. What I don't understand, in which circumstances is PCA any better than simply removing some features from the model? If the aim is to obtain lower dimensional data, why don't we just group those features that are correlated and retain one single feature from each group?

Comment: This is a good question, but it's better suited to [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), which is the stats/ML sibling to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference between **feature reduction** (such as PCA) and **feature selection** (which you describe). The crucial difference is that feature reduction (PCA) maps your data to lower dimensional through some projection of **all** original dimensions, for example PCA uses linear combination of each. So final data embedding has information from **all features**. If you perform **feature selection** you **discard** information, you completely loose anything that was present there. Furthermore, PCA guarantees you retaining given fraction of the data variance.

Comment: As far as I understood, with PCA we eliminate dimensions that are correlated, ie linearly dependent. That said, projecting all those dimensions doesn't seem to retain any more information than just dropping them... Am I missing something?

Comment: That has nothing to do with PCA. Pca looks for a linear projection which preserves most of the variance. It does not "eliminate" any dimensions.